# What should the minimum voltage rating of replacement power resistors be?

Tags: amplifier, resistors, audio

I'm looking for four power resistors of the same type to replace R87, R88, R89, and R90 in the POWER AMP section of the amplifier of Klipsch SW-12 subwoofer shown below:

[image: R87, R88, R89, R90]

What should the minimum voltage rating of the following new resistors be?

Choice 1:

5W 1.5K ohm

Choice 2:

5W 1K ohm

Choice 3:

7W 1k ohm

Choice 4:

7W 750 ohm

Choices 1-3 all have their voltage rating listed (350V - 500V), but I can't find the voltage rating for Choice 4:

http://www.newark.com/multicomp/mcprm07wjp751b00/metal-film-resistor-750-ohm-7w/dp/16R1987?exaMfpn=true&categoryId=&searchRef=SearchLookAhead&searchView=table&iscrfnonsku=false

Datasheet:

http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1679919.pdf?_ga=1.219978905.1878132867.1486504283

If I can't find the voltage rating for Choice 4, should I drop it from my list of choices for the replacement resistors?

[A picture showing R88 and R90 with four other white resistors: Added 2/13/17]

There's a similar-looking row of six white resistors on the other side of the amp, too (bottom in the picture).

[image: six white resistors]

[Added 2/13/17]

I received a reply from a US distributor of the Choice 4 resistor:

Received: Mon, Feb 13, 2017 9:33 am
Subject: MCPRM07WJP751B00

Hi

The max voltage rating is 500v.  I don’t have a data sheet to send but the product manager was able to contact the mfg to get the voltage.

Have a nice day.

. . . . . . . . . . .

[Added 2/14/17]

This is the resistor's listing that prompted me to ask a question about voltage rating for resistors:

http://www.newark.com/cgs-te-connectivity/sbche61k0j/wirewound-resistor-1kohm-7w-5/dp/16R6555

I hadn't been able to find it until this morning.

Comment: all resistor choices meet the voltage requirements of 50V. Since 80/2=40 Why are you worried?

Comment: @Tony Steward: I'm not quite sure what power rating and voltage rating of resistors are. I thought I'd better ask knowledgeable people here. R87-R90 get hot and I'm looking to replace them with resistors of different rating. The related question is here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/285529/1-5-k%ce%a9-resistors-vs-750-%ce%a9-resistors

Comment: @zeron Considering that one of the resistors desoldered itself and the close proximity of the resistors to each other (thus reducing their power dissipation capability), you might want to see if you can find metal-encased power resistors and attach them to something (e.g. a sheet of aluminium) to increase their power-dissipation capability. But it lasted for 20 years as it was, so maybe not worth bothering with.

Comment: @Andrew Morton: Thank you for your suggestion, but as you can see in the picture I just linked, the space around them is really tight. The reason one of the resistors desoldered itself could have been caused by a short I created while touching up solder joints. I eliminated the short and with a temporary resistor in R88's place (just hanged from the through holes), the amp worked OK. So, my guess is that they get really hot, but not hot enough to desolder themselves under normal condition.

Comment: 300-500V is not a power rating. You're asking about voltage rating but you're only quoting power rating and resistance. Please clarify what you're actually asking about.

Comment: @EJP: Oh, sorry, I meant voltage rating. I make corrections in the original post.

Comment: @zeron Given the physical constraints on dimensions, i.e. they are right next to each other, just make sure the resistors you choose fit in the available space and do a final check that they have the correct pin spacing by consulting the datasheets.

Comment: @Andrew Morton: Thank you for your concerns. The one I'm thinking of getting now has the following dimensions: 38 x 12.5 x 9 mm (each +/- 1mm), opposed to the original's 26.5 x 12.7 x 9.8 mm. The pin spacing is about 5 mm for both, and yes, the footprint is about the same as well. I'll replace all four originals with four new ones. I'm pretty sure the new ones will fit in the originals' locations.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't worry about this too much.  The implicit minimum voltage rating of a resistor is

V = sqrt(W Ω)

where V is the voltage, W the power in Watts, and Ω the resistance in Ohms.  If it were anything less, then the resistor couldn't dissipate the rated power.

The lowest of your choices is the 5 W 1 kΩ resistor, which must be able to handle at least 71 V to dissipate its rated 5 W.

This circuit has ±81 V supplies, with four of these resistors in series from one supply to the other.  Assume worst case that the center point can be driven to either rail, so 162 V across two resistors in series.  It looks like the resistors will divide that fairly evenly, so a bit over 80 V across any one of them worst case.

Any resistor you find that can dissipate 5 W or more is going to be physically big enough to handle well over 100 V.  You're not going to be able to find a resistor that meets the power and resistance requirements that can't handle whatever voltage this circuit can possibly throw at it.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, what do you think is wrong?

Comment: I certainly wouldn't call it wrong nor downvoted but it does lack consideration for ambient of adjacent equal powered R's and de-rating by perhaps 50% for 1 side and more on both sides.

Answer (score 2):

The question now says, "minimum voltage rating". The answer is obvious: since the power supply is +-80V, the resistors could not be exposed to signals of more than 160V. This is the formal answer - 160V. Any resistor of this size would probably exceed this rating.

I am not sure though what the actual problem is that needs to be addressed. What has failed? Why to replace the resistors? Too high temperature of the resistors, so they de-solder and fall off?

Comment: The amp started generating noises in January this year when it's warmed up. The four resistors definitely contribute to the amp getting hot. Something else in the amp could be causing overheating, but these resistors must be changed because one of them definitely failed after desoldering itself: it reads only 426 ohms or so now. One interesting thing is that the BOM for the amp lists the resistors as 5W 1.5K ohms. It's likely that the original resistors' values may not have been optimal, so I want to replace them with ones that are compatible and will help the amp run cooler.

Comment: @zeron, all indications are that you have half of your amp seriously blown out, so replacing the simple resistor divider will NOT solve your problem. Reading of resistor's values in-circuit could be anything, because there are other paths for current that will contribute to measurements. You need to test ALL TRANSISTORS in your amp for functionality if you want to fix it. If it doesn't smoke right away with no signal, try to measure DC voltages at every point, and watch for Vbe to be less than 0.7V.

Comment: "... all indications are that you have half of your amp seriously blown out...." Can half-blown amps drive woofers to make musically coherent sounds? Mine does. However, the output level may have dropped by 3dBor a little more. I don't want to increase the volume too much because the woofer is outside of its intended enclosure now. Is it possible that only like the positive side of the amp is amplifying the signal? But if that's what's happening, I'd expect much more severe distortion. Also, with the plastic cover off, noises usually don't show up for hours.

Comment: Replacing the four resistors didn't solve the noise problem. Touching up the solder joints of the three pins of Q9 did. I wouldn't have reached the solution without learning a lot from posts here. Thanks. More detail is here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/289929/setting-the-bias-for-the-power-amp-section-of-an-audio-amplifier#388211

Answer (score 1):

Each 750ohm part dissipates <2.5W or 50% of 5W suggested rating so with convection air flow and raised above the board should be ok with ventilation. Expect it to be 100'C or 80'C above ambient. Any smaller rating will need more air flow.

Comment: Stewart: You wouldn't go with resistors with higher power rating or higher ohm value? I'll add a picture of the amplifier with its cover off to the original post soon. As you'll be able to see in the picture, the ambient temperature could keep rising. (I actually drilled some holes to the plastic case that originally had not holes for ventilation.)

Comment: same value is best for bias regulation, higher power rating allows cooler operation. Value is a tradeoffs between current limit and Pd

Comment: Stewart: "same value is best for bias regulation, higher power rating allows cooler operation." So, would you say that the 7W 750 ohm one is a good choice? The distributor that carries it confirmed that its voltage rating is 500V.

Comment: use what the original BOM says

Comment: The original BOM says 1.5K 5W.

Comment: "use what the original BOM says" Tony, there's a discrepancy between the BOM and the schematic of SW-12 in the service manual of SW-12/15: http://www.audiolabga.com/pdf/SW12-15%20I.pdf   The thread that asks about this is here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/285529/1-5-k%ce%a9-resistors-vs-750-%ce%a9-resistors

Comment: The big problem with this design is NPN, PNP must be matched and pot adjusted to null DC out and the MJF15030 may be very linear but very low hFE so the base resistor bias can get pulled by offset in hFE between +/- sides

Comment: If you cannot nul the output < 0,1V then there is an excess hFE inbalance. 750 improves this at the expense of excess heat. so replace with matched Q's as required.

Comment: Tony, thank you very much for your answers and comments. Before seeing your latest comments on this topic, I ordered six 7W 750 ohm resistors, figuring that since I don't have all the equipment needed to re-calibrate the output levels as described in the service manual, getting resistors of the same resistance as the original would be safer. Thanks again for your detailed analysis.

Comment: any DMM can measure null DC out. This is a crucial step to ensure high & matched hFE's to prevent overloading R's with offsets. each divider should be close to V+/2

Comment: "any DMM can measure null DC out." This is beyond me. I'd appreciate it if you could guide me thorough this. I've replaced three of the four resistors with 7W 750 ohm ones. (One wasn't replaced because I couldn't remove it.) What/where/how do I measure/adjust null DC? Is this different from the DC offset adjustment (R50) described in the DRIVER CIRCUIT section on Page 3 of the service manual? If the null DC measurement is to be taken at the two speaker output leads, do I need to attach a load to them, like a 16-ohm 200W one required for re-alignment described in the service manual? Thanks.

Comment: Yes that is the same procedure where it says OUT, it must be 0Vdc. The load is to ensure stability, I believe. But if you dont have a load R, you can still try to check OUT DC level with a voltmeter.

Comment: Tony, Thank you for responding quickly. Is it OK to connect the original woofer's terminals to the +/- speaker leads and take a measurement at the woofer's terminals? The original woofer's nominal impedance is 8 ohms. (This way, the amp has some load.) And I adjust the variable resistor 50 (Schematic Sheet 2), right?

Comment: No if you have high DC voltage on woofer, the braid wire can be damaged. Use a light bulb if you dont have anything else. There is a Relay between Terminal H and speak + output. So H is the best place with no load.

Comment: I adjusted R50 successfully yesterday. The reading was about +30mV, so it was still within the tolerance (+/- 50mV). It gently fluctuates (goes up/down about 30mV) in the first several minutes of operation. I set it so that the reading stabilizes around -0.2mV (+/-15mV). I may still have some problems with other parts of the amp, but I'm done with this resistor part. Thank you all who posted in any of the threads I started in the last several weeks for helping me reach this point, especially Tony and Olin.