# Setting the bias for the power amp section of an audio amplifier?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, resistors, audio, bias

I've been working on the internal amplifier of SW-12 active subwoofer. I started suspecting its power amp section may not be working properly. (I get musically coherent sound out of the attached woofer, but the volume seems to be lower than before I started fooling around with the amp.).

Since I have changed R88, R89, and R90 (with the resistors of the same resistance rating but with 7W power rating), I think I'd better check if the bias for the power amp section is correct, at the least.

How do I do that? Can somebody guide me through this?

What mode do I set my multimeter to and measure where?

I have numbered various points in the schematic of the power amp section:

[image: Schematic: Power Amp section of SW-12]

Oh, and what should the value/s be?

Do the LEVEL, PHASE, and LOW PASS settings matter when I do this?

How about signal going into the amp's LINE in? Is no signal fine?

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

The service manual for SW-12 is here:

http://www.audiolabga.com/pdf/SW12-15%20I.pdf

As far as I can tell, it doesn't mention anything about setting the bias for the power amp section of the amplifier.

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

Update (3/6/17):

Per jonk's guidance, I have checked the following:

+/- 81 volt rails: about +/- 91 volts;

+/- 15 volt rails: about +/- 15 volts;

voltage across two zener diodes, D5 & D6: +33.6V and -33.6V, respectively

Per Tonny Elliot's guidance, I had checked/adjusted R50 to make the DC offset at the speaker output 0V +/- 10mV or so (within spec) before starting the thread here.

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

A picture added (3/8/17):

R66, R67, R139 (brown resistor), and C55. I thought some of you might find this configuration interesting.

[image: R66, R67, R139, and C55]

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

2 pictures showing speaker output V, A, and V*A added (3/11/17)

The load attached is a space heater with 17.2 ohms (not exactly 16 ohms as required for the alignment procedure described in Service Manual), but good enough for taking these readings, isn't it?

Adjusting R84 doesn't seem to affect these numbers significantly, by the way.

[image: charts pt. 1]

[image: charts pt.2]

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

Further thought - Added (3/13/17)

After looking at the numbers (V, A, and V*A of the speaker output) and the accompanying charts above last night, I started thinking maybe the amplifier is OK. I don't like abrupt changes I see around LEVEL 6~7, but that how the circuit for this amplifier may have been designed. When this subwoofer was working fine, LEVEL 7 (1 o'colock) was about the highest I used. If this is the case, I don't know why I feel the sound lacks energy today. (I can't rule out the possibility of the woofer being damaged.)

Can somebody tell whether the numbers above look at least reasonably OK or absolutely not?

According to the specs for my subwoofer, SW=12, the maximum rated output is 150W into 8 ohm. (The input sensitivity for max rated output is listed as 60mVrms for LINE IN.) If my reasoning is correct, the voltage required to deliver 150W into 8 ohms is 34.6V. So, the amplifier seems to be amplifying the signal enough. or does it?

Several hours later. . .

I just remembered this comment of mine that I posted on March 9:

jonk: "Also, consider examining R34, too, which sets the gain." I made a test CD with 30 Hz. sine signal. Per instructions in the service manual, I set the output of the receiver to 60mV and measured the output of the subwoofer's amplifier with a 17.2 ohm dummy load connected. The voltage was about 20V. I increased the gain to make the output voltage about 33V (per spec). I found the sound quality got noticeably worse.

I hadn't touched R34 until then, so a part or parts of amplification may be missing. As to R30, the output voltage is noticeably lower than the spec's value, but I can't increase it because R30 had been rotated CW (to increase) fully.

Comment: \$R_{84}\$ is part of a \$V_{BE}\$ multiplier. So that's the resistor to adjust to set "bias." You don't mention that fact, but I hope you already realize it. Do you know why it's there? (It doesn't have Early Effect compensation. But that's another issue.)

Comment: I guessed R84 is the one to adjust, but I don't know why it's there. I'm a novice in electronics. So, you adjust R84, but measure what where?

Comment: I'll write a little. Your question is too big to consider writing a full manual for. Before I do, though, I assume you've already checked the voltage rails?? What do they look like?

Comment: If it's not clear, you should definitely check out the \$\pm 15\:\textrm{V}\$ voltage rails (against ground) and also the \$\pm 81\:\textrm{V}\$ rails. There are some \$34\:\textrm{V}\$ zeners in there on page 2 of the schematic. You might also want to check the voltages on those, as well. For starters. I don't know how old your unit is. But replacing all the electrolytics comes to mind, as well. The do get old. So how old is this unit?

Comment: Over 20 years old. No, I haven't measured +/-15V rails or +/-81V rails yet since I'm new to this and don't feel comfortable taking live measurements. For 81V rails, do I set my multimeter to DC mode and attach its negative probe to L and the positive probe to D or E? The heat sink of the amp seems to be grounded. Should I use the heat sink instead of L? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just keep in mind you may have to replace **ALL** of the electrolytics to restore this unit. (I'd probably "just do it," no matter what.) Yes, DC mode. Yes, LGND is good for ground reference. Keep in mind that +81 gets the red lead and LGND the black. But -81 gets the black lead and LGND the red lead, if your voltmeter doesn't do negative values. (Some do, some don't.)

Comment: I hope I did this right, but L-E measured -91.3V and L-D measured +91.1V. My multimeter is probably NOT true RMS type. Does this matter for these readings?

Comment: That's fine and, no, RMS capability isn't required here. (Of course I'm assuming you are being careful!) Those readings don't surprise me. I'll add a short post about the multiplier I mentioned and what to look for elsewhere. (A little bit, anyway.)

Comment: I measured A-C and B-C (15V): They are both pretty close to 0 (zero). Since I thought that the solder joint that appears to be labeled "C" on a circuit board (1 of 2 PCBs) may not be really "C," I measured A and C against the amp's chassis (back plate with heat sink). The readings were the same (fluctuating around 0.0V, never above/below +/- 0.2V or so).

Comment: Those are AC points, not DC. You need to find \$C_{23}\$ and \$C_{24}\$ and measure the voltage across those using a DC measurement. (It's beginning to sound to me like you really aren't at a point where you should be trouble-shooting this yourself. So this may no longer be the right place, as it's not arranged for training lessons.)

Comment: I located C23 and C24.

Comment: c23 measures about 14.5V. C24 measures about -15.07V. Thank you for your guidance and patience, jonk. I think we can at least assume that the transformer is not dead or severely damaged.

Comment: Read the manual you found and follow the instructions for \$R_{50}\$ to zero the output leads without an input signal applied. Also, consider examining \$R_{34}\$, too, which sets the gain.

Comment: I adjusted R50 several days ago. I made the output 0V  +/- 10~20 mV (within the tolerance range stated in the service manual). Before adjusting R50, the output was a tad higher than 0V, but still within +/-50 mV. As to R34 (and R30), I don't have a signal generator, so I can't check/adjust them now.

Comment: jonk: "Also, consider examining R34, too, which sets the gain." I made a test CD with 30 Hz. sine signal. Per instructions in the service manual, I set the output of the receiver to 60mV and measured the output of the subwoofer's amplifier with a 17.2 ohm dummy load connected. The voltage was about 20V. I increased the gain to make the output voltage about 33V (per spec). I found the sound quality got noticeably worse. When I measure the current at output, the current increases as I turn the LEVEL know clockwise (from less than 1 amp to over 10 amp easily).

Comment: "When I measure the current at output, the current increases as I turn the LEVEL know clockwise (from less than 1 amp to over 10 amp easily)." Correction: "When I measure the current at output, the current increases as I turn the LEVEL knob clockwise (from milli amp to over 1 amp easily)."

Comment: I took a quick "sanity check" of the schematic and I can't make the final stage work all that well in my mind. I'm sure there was a designer working on it. But the VBE multiplier just doesn't seem to provide enough separation. I'll look again, tonight. See what I think.

Comment: I just noticed you wrote that \$R_{139}=25\:\Omega\$?? Seriously? You've got to mean thousands of Ohms. Right?

Comment: "I just noticed you wrote that R139=25Ω??" Sorry, my mistake:  both R66 and R139 read about 25K ohms. I should cut one lead of each and take a measurement. I haven't done so yet. (I tend to think they are all right because R66 read about 28K before I started noticing the bad quality in sound, if I remember correctly. I can't be certain about this.)

Comment: There are a lot of things that may affect "bad quality." I looked at the VBE multiplier. It might be okay. It might not be. If it isn't okay, then you'd certainly experience cross-over distortion. But I think you need a trouble-shooting process to walk through. Since it is "mostly working" except for "bad quality," I would start at the final output stage and work backwards. Others might go the other way. Are you interested in my just starting an answer and then walking you through the "start at the output stage" and work back from there? Or do you already have a process in mind?

Comment: "Are you interested in my just starting an answer and then walking you through the 'start at the output stage' and work back from there?" Sure, but you might want to look at the data and charts I added to my original post. LEVEL 5 (11 o'clock) used to give satisfactory bass. I never felt the need to go past LEVEL 7 (1 o'clock) because the whole room started shaking at that level. Today, the bass lacks oomph and turning LEVEL knob past noon makes the woofer to start "flapping" without giving any appreciable increase in bass, while making the excursion of the voice coil excessive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the power amp section is really the output stage (OPS). The input and vas stages are in the driver circuit.

the ops is quite innovative. to check bias of it, measure voltage across j/m -> should be around 4v -> 6 pn junctions.

or you can check the voltage across emitter resistors on Q16/17/19/20/22/23/25/26. they should be roughly the same.

but I doubt they are the issues. your issues sound like gain setting / protection. check r66/67/167 and c55, the input circuitry. having a signal generator + scope would be helpful.

Comment: dannyf: "but I doubt they are the issues. your issues sound like gain setting / protection. check r66/67/167 and c55, the input circuitry." When I was touching up some solder joints, I inadvertently created a short around R88 and R90. I've been thinking that running the amp with the short could have damaged some components. I'll check the components you mention, but I can't seem to locate R167. Is the number correct? Thanks.

Comment: dannyf: "check r66/67/167 and c55, the input circuitry." The following measurements were taken with the components in circuit: R66 = ~20.8 ohms. R67 = ~0.98Kohms. R139 = ~ 20.7 ohms. I don't have the capability to measure capacitance at the moment. The schematic indicates that R66 is supposed to be 39.2K ohm and R139 39K ohm (and their color codes agree with these numbers). Do you think it's worth the trouble to take their measurements off the circuit?

Comment: R139/R66 = 20ohm sounds way too long to be correct. if that's measured correctly, it can definitely contribute to low gain. but how did you measure it?

Comment: dannyf: "but how did you measure it?" All in the circuit. I can understand R139's reading being affected by C55 or others, but I expected R66 to be not affected by others. I measured their resistance by touching their two leads with my multimeter's probes. Interestingly, about a month ago, R66 read about 28K ohms, according to my note. Again in circuit. I'll see if I can get a picture of this area.

Comment: i just took readings of R66 and R139. They both read about 25 ohms now. (About 10 hours ago, I turned on the amplifier for testing.)

Comment: "(About 10 hours ago, I turned on the amplifier for testing.)" I forgot to mention that I turned off the amplifier after 10 minutes or so of testing. So, the amplifier had been off for about 10 hours before I took the readings of the two resistors this morning.

Comment: in circuit measurement isn't that precise, especially if the amp is powered on. Also, resistors rarely go bad, or go bad short. So I'm not sure if I would trust the measurement 100%. But as a trial, see if you put in a in-spec resistor as R66 and if that fixes the problem. good luck.

Comment: just saw the picture. For R66, cut one of the leads and measure it again. if it is still 20R, put in a resistor of the right size between the cut lead and pcb and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: "For R66, cut one of the leads and measure it again. if it is still 20R, put in a resistor of the right size between the cut lead and pcb and see if that fixes the problem. " Good idea. Thanks. How do I read the voltage across J/M? Do I use AC or DC setting? Does a input signal have to be present and LEVEL on the amplifier high? If I remember correctly, I tried both AC & DC with the unit on, no signal and 0 volume and got almost 0 volts ( only a few hundred mV.) I didn't pursue much because I wasn't sure what I was supposed to be doing.

Comment: dannyf: "check r66/67/167[139?] and c55" The following measurements were taken with the components in circuit: R66 = ~20.8K ohms. R67 = ~0.98Kohms. R139 = ~20.7K ohms. (The values in my comment dated 3/8/17 contained typos.) Looking at the schematic, I suspect that ~20K is the value of the combined resistance of R66, R67, and R139 (Sheet 2) and R87, R88, R89, and R90 (Sheet 3) in the parallel circuits they form, so R66, R139 are probably all right. I still would like to check if C55 when I can. When I check C55, I can check R139 "off the circuit" for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Because I got busy with other things I had to take care of, I stopped on restoring the subwoofer around March, 2017. (The original problem was making a crackling noise after warming up.)

Because the area of the circuit board where R87, R88, R89, and R90 were was getting hot and one of the resistors actually burned out, I replaced three of them with resistors of the same ohm (750 ohm) but with higher wattage (7W instead of 5W). (One of the four resistors was hard to remove, so I left the original.) While this replacement of the three resistors may have helped to reduce the the overheating problem, the original noise remained. This was all I did before stopping on the subwoofer last year.

I resumed working on the subwoofer about two weeks ago. I replaced on original remaining resistors of the four and changed C55 this time, but the noise remained.

I decided to go back to square one two nights ago and started looking for bad solder joints on the circuit board. I noticed that if I wiggle the heat sink of Q9, the noise gets affected. I tested further with cooling the heat sink with a Q-tip  moistened with alcohol and confirmed that the temperature on the heat sink (= the temperature of Q9) was the cause of the noise. I touched up the solder joints of pins of Q9 and pins of several other components near it. On the first try, I tried to do this minimally on the pins of Q9 fearing damaging it with too much heat. Upon testing, I found the noise was still there. Deciding that I'll just replace the transistor if damaged, I did resoldering the pins of Q9 thoroughly with more solder. After this, the noise disappeared completely. I listened to music for several hours last night. The subwoofer sounds more robust than before. (After replacing the four resistors and one capacitor, I recalibrated R34, R30, and VDC offset. Maybe this helped. Also my impression that the sound level was lower than before may have been purely subjective. After putting the woofer back into its cabinet and sealing it as it should be, it sounds robust again.)

I thank everyone who posted on my threads about the subwoofer. I started knowing almost nothing about electronics and that's is still true today, but I have learned a lot from people here. Thanks again.

"You always find what you're looking for at the last place you look."

(The first thing I did was actually touching up all suspicious looking solder joints, but Q9's solder joints looked OK even through a magnifying glass. Trying other harder things and failing to produce the desired result was a necessary step to go look harder all over.)