# Selecting good replacement resistors for SW-12's R87, R88, R89, and R90

Tags: amplifier, resistors, audio

Related questions I have posted here so far:

[1.5 kΩ resistors vs. 750 Ω resistors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/285529/1-5-k%ce%a9-resistors-vs-750-%ce%a9-resistors)

[What should the minimum voltage rating of replacement power resistors be?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/286327/what-should-the-minimum-voltage-rating-of-replacement-power-resistors-be)

Thanks to those who answered or commented on the questions above, I'm ready to order replacement resistors for R87, R88, R89, and R90 highlighted below:

[image: R87-R90]

The main objective of replacing the current resistors with ones with different values is to help the amplifier run as cool as possible because the originals seem to get hot enough to make the amplifier unstable. (I wouldn't mind some reduction in the output power, etc.) So, with this objective in mind, what would be the best and the second best choices as.45 the replacement resistors, among the following? (They all fit in the originals' locations, and they're all available for immediate shipping in the US today.)

Choice 1:

5W 1.5K ohm (same foot print, volume, surface area as the original's)

Choice 2:

5W 1K ohm (same foot print, volume, surface area as the original's)

Choice 3:

7W 1k ohm (same foot print, but volume and surface area bigger than the original's)

Choice 4:

7W 750 ohm (same foot print, but volume and surface area bigger than the original's)

Comment: This is your fourth attempt at this question. Why split essentially the same question into four separate questions? You can edit you know.

Comment: This is now the tenth question you have posted on this same repair, and this is getting tiresome, as well as cluttering up the site with information that is unlikely to be of use to anyone else. Please stop! If you have additional information for one of your previous questions, **edit the question** rather than posting a new one.

Comment: @Dave Tweed: OK. I'm not familiar with the format here. In most other forums, editing your posts is considered more confusing because some may have responded to your posts as they were and their responses may look out of place later. I'll try to minimize redundancy in my posts, but this one is a little different from all other posts I've made on resistors. I'm asking two best choices as final choices.

Comment: This is not a forum. It is a website that is attempting to create a repository of generally-useful information in a question-and-answer format. You might want to [re-take the tour](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) before proceeding further.

Comment: This effort is misdirected. The amp apparently has few blown transistors in the upper part of circuit. If the amp was working for 10 years  before, nothing is wrong with the resistors or their values.

Comment: @Ali: "The amp apparently has few blown transistors in the upper part of circuit." What do you mean by "the upper part of circuit"? If some transistors are blown, I thought they'd be one or more of Q21, Q22, Q23, Q24, Q25, and Q26. Would be hard to reach them. I'd have to disassemble the whole rig and desolder about a dozen wires between two PCBs. Another area of the amp I know gets hot is Q7, Q8, Q9, and Q10 in DRIVER CKT (Schematic Sheet 2).